# Should a binding redirect work for external dlls?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015, postsharp, assembly-binding-redirect

Scenario:

I just upgraded all the projects in my solution to a new version of PostSharp (shouldn't matter the library, hopefully.)  I have around 20 projects in my solution and around half of them originally referenced version 3.0.42 and I just updated them all to the latest version.  My solution contains a web app that references projects within this solution, as well as some external dll references.  It just so happens that some of those dll references also had dependencies on PostSharp version 3.0.42 and I'm now getting the typical "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference." error from those external dlls when trying to run my app.  The web.config has the appropriate bindingdirect in place.  Is there any way to have the bindingrediect impact my external dlls as well?  Rebuilding them with the latest PostSharp dll is not currently an option.

Comment: Use Fuslogvw.exe to find out why your binding redirects are not effective.

Comment: @HansPassant I got Fuslogvw running and it shows the the failure but I don't see any detail that points me to a root cause.  Anything specific that I should be looking for?

Comment: In the Fusion log you should see all the DLLs that the CLR attempts to load and the description what exactly didn't match in each case. This usually gives a good hint about what's going wrong. Normally, the binding redirects should work for the dependencies of external DLLs as well.